# GDB backtrace variables values

Tags: c, gdb

The values of pointers in the different frames of a gdb backtrace:

- Are the values that the variables had in that moment of execution?
- Or are the values that GDB have in the stack when the sefault happened?

For example, if I get the phy_rad value in frame 3 and 4 (both are pointing to the same address) Can I detect changes switching from frame 3 to frame 4?

```
    #0  0x00419561 in list_del_free_func_ (l=0x76e11b90, f_free_node=0x0, release_func=0x4192d9 ) at src/util/util.c:174                                                                                
    #1  0x00419613 in list_del_free_func (l=0x76e11b90, f_free_node=0x0) at src/util/util.c:192              
    #2  0x004b3355 in store_scan_info (scan_res=0x9cb060, phy_rad=0x9c7ed4) at bla.c:312                                                                                                      
    #3  0x004b36fd in get_scan_freq_obj (phy_rad=0x9c7ed4, chans=0x99c134, radio_mac=0x76e11c70 "\004\360!\033\367\247\017") at bla.c:381                                                     
    #4  0x004b3c63 in WVIC_scan (arg=0x9c7e90) at bla.c:454                         
    #5  0x770b5689 in ?? ()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A colleague has given me an example and it is the the stack state at the time of failure.